# Debugging of the console application ended without waiting for the process created under to finish

Tags: c#, console-application, ui-thread

When I run a C# console application, it creates a parallel process; now, my main application threads must wait until the process created under it is closed; however, in my case, the main ui thread exited when the process start code was executed; it did not wait for the created process to end.

```
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command)
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,

            };
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processInfo;
        process.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("This line should be print after the process ended");
```

How do I keep the main UI thread waiting until the process I've started completes?

Comment: Did you miss `process.WaitForExit()`?

Comment: @Serg what if i have more than one process to be created

Comment: @max Then you need to keep a list of the process instances and wait for all of them to end.

Comment: @PMF im invoking process Exit event when it is created, then obviously main thread should wait right until exit event trigger for corresponding process?

Comment: Yes, that should work, too. Of course, if you have multiple processes, you still need to keep track of all of them.

Comment: @max, no, your thread will not wait for exit event without explicit wait instruction. So, if you just do something like `processs.Exited += handler;`, your process still may finish prior event will be fired.